# How to center vertically <kbd> content inside an <div>

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a piano, but im starting by the basics.
Im dweling with centering the inside content of the **div**.
I want the  to be right in the middle and centered inside his father div

heres the code:
html

```
    <div class="keys">
            <div class="key" id="keyA">
                <kbd>A</kbd>
            </div>
            <div class="key" id="keyS">
                <kbd>S</kbd>
            </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: chocolate;
}

.keys{
    padding: 4px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 40%;
    max-height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: white solid;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;


}
.key{
    border: black solid 1px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    max-height: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    width: 70px;
    max-width: 95%;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
kbd{
    /*border to see the with and weight*/
    border: pink solid 1px;
    color: aliceblue;
  

}
```

heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnd9jr4y/
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is only working on the direct content of a flexbox container. To additonal center the Name of the keys add to `.key` additional 'flex-settings'.

Have a look to the example below:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: chocolate;
}

.keys{
    padding: 4px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 40%;
    max-height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: white solid;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;


}
.key{
    border: black solid 1px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    max-height: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    width: 70px;
    max-width: 95%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    /* JUST ADD */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 

}
kbd{
    /*border to see the with and weight*/
    border: pink solid 1px;
    color: aliceblue;
    
   
  

}
```

```html
    <div class="keys">
            <div class="key" id="keyA">
                <kbd>A</kbd>
            </div>
            <div class="key" id="keyS">
                <kbd>S</kbd>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox

```
.key{
    border: black solid 1px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    max-height: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    width: 70px;
    max-width: 95%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; // vertical centering
    justify-content: center; // horizontal centering
}
```